# ListView doesn't refresh when last item is deleted

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-listfragment

I have problem in my app. I have CursorLoader in conjcution with CursorAdapter. Everything works as expected, except one condition: when I have some items on ListView and I swap cursor in adapter for cursor that is empty, visible items aren't deleted (only dividers between rows disappear). When I touch ListView it disappears instantly.

Here is the situation. I have some non empty cursor:
[image]

Then I swap for cursor that has no results:
[image]

As you can see only dividers disappeard. After touching the screen both items disappear.

Here is my function that swaps cursor:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
{
    ratesAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
```

Fragment source: http://pastebin.com/N2YGzgRj

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried a `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after your `delete()` ?

Comment: Can we see some more code ? Are you notifying the data set on the adapter through notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: Here is my whole source to this Fragment: http://pastebin.com/N2YGzgRj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after investigating problem a little bit more, I found that this problem only applies to Android 4.0.x. This bug doesn't exist in 2.2, 2.3 or 4.1, only 4.0. The only way for me to solve this bug is to add to onLoadFinished()

```
getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
getListView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I don't find it elegant way, bu maybe you will have some ideas.

Comment: Blah, accidentally downvoted and can't change it. *sigh* Sorry :/

Comment: This is still a bug in 5.0, and I tried every method available to get the ListView to refresh after removing all items.  This is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

not including `notifyDataSetChanged();` is usually the cause of these listView not refreshing issues. Trying to include that after your loading code is all i can recommend 'till i get more information.

Comment: adding notifyDataSetChanged() in onLoadFinished() didn't help. Situation is the same.

Comment: Are you sure onLoadFinished is called at all? Try to set a Log.d inside the method.

Comment: I set Log.d inside onLoadFinised(). Function is called properly.